# How to solve "Could not find or load main class.." in Eclipse workplace

Tags: java, eclipse, testing

I'm create chrome testing function in eclipse.

The program have no error. But wile executing the program it shows following error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class CrossBrowserTesting.ChromeTesting
>   Caused by: 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CrossBrowserTesting.ChromeTesting

But I didn't have idea Why this error is appear. Because My code has no error.

I enclose my code as below,

```
package CrossBrowserTesting;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class ChromeTesting {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       WebDriver driver;
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","\\selenium webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.get("https://www.example.com");
       driver.quit();

   }

}
```

My file structure is

```
-- Foldername
  -- src
    -- CrossBrowserTesting
       -- ChromeTesting
```

Comment: Clean the project from menu --> project --> clean (select the project and clean)

Comment: I am sorry. I am new in eclipse. So i did not know how to clean in eclipse.

Comment: I found `clean up` option. It is you mean that in `menu --> project --> clean`.

Comment: *How* are you telling it to execute your program?

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project, You can find clean... option in Project tab between Search and Run.
[image]

Comment: Ok. I try this option.

Comment: This option is not working to me fix my issue. If any possible to solve my issue to import new jdk in eclipse

Comment: If you are using Maven please right click on project  and update the project, If not then restart of eclipse may help.

Comment: I use eclipse IDE java 2019-03

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, I have solved this problem by go to menu : Project>clean

and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar problem a few days ago, steps which I follow to resolve the issue

1. Right click on Project(a project that showing error)
2. Go to the build path section and then click on configure build project.
3. Now remove the JRE library.
4. Now click on add library and click on JRE system library.
5. Now click on Execution environment and then finish.

Hope the error is gone now, It happens because sometimes some JRE file missed.